# Creating a new node style with three circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm trying to create a node that is three circles, arranged in a triangle pattern (one on the top and two on the bottom, see below).

Not really sure if it would be possible to define a new style and if so how to go about it.

The ideal would then to be able to use the command:

```
\node (test) [threeCircles] {};
```

[image: Three circles]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33150/15925 help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `pic` which is kind of a "subfigure" which can be later placed, rotated or scaled as if it was a node.

For example, this could be the pic:

```
\tikzset{
mynode/.pic={
   \coordinate (center) at (0,0);
   \fill[top color=blue!50!cyan!40!white, bottom color=blue!40!black] (90:#1) circle(0.1);
   \fill[top color=blue!50!cyan!40!white, bottom color=blue!40!black] (-30:#1) circle(0.1);
   \fill[top color=blue!50!cyan!40!white, bottom color=blue!40!black] (210:#1) circle(0.1);
   },
pics/mynode/.default=0.2
}
```

The `(center)` coordinate is a name suffix which can be later be used to connect such a pics.

To use these pics you put them as part of a `\path` command. The syntax is similar to a node, but using `pic` instead of `node`, and putting the kind of pic in braces, instead of the text of the node. I.e: `pic[options] (name) {kind}`. In this example, `kind` would be `mynode`.

The following example uses three of these pics at different coordinates, scales and rotations. Then two of them are joined by an arrow.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0)  pic            (p1) {mynode} 
      (1,0)  pic[rotate=90] (p2) {mynode} 
      (0,1)  pic[scale=0.5] (p3) {mynode};
\draw[->] (p3center) to[bend left] (p2center);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that the coordinates used to draw the arrow are `p3center` and `p2center`, which are the concatenation of the "outer" name of each pic with the "inner" name of one coordinate/node inside the pic. This way you can define "anchors" for each of the three inner circles, if required.

Result:

[image: Result]

The definition of the pic uses polar coordinates around `(0,0)` to position the three blue circles. The distance to that origin is the parameter `#1` which has the default value `0.2`. You can give it another value if you write `pic {myshape=0.5}`, for example.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I ended up using this one as it was the most appropriate in the situation.

Answer (score 5):

You may create a new command and use it with parametrical coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\threeCircles}[2]{%
    \node[circle,blue,fill=blue] (a) at (#1,#2) {};
    \node[circle,blue,fill=blue] at ($(a)+(.3,-.4)$) {}; 
    \node[circle,blue,fill=blue] at ($(a)+(-.3,-.4)$) {}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \threeCircles{1}{1};
        \threeCircles{4}{1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]