# Tikz node form as open half circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

A typical form for a node in TikZ is a circle around the text of the node. The shapes packages provides lot of other forms. What I couldn't find is an open half circle (or ellipse) under the node. Any ideas or hints on that?
Cheers
Renger

Comment: Are you searching for `semicircle`?

Comment: No, semicircle is upside down and is closed, I want to have it open (like a bowl below the node)

Comment: See this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33150/creating-node-shapes

How do I mark a question as duplicate?

Comment: How about `\node(A){some text};` and then `\draw(A.west)to[bend right=45](A.east);`?

Answer (score 4):

This is mainly inspired from:
[Creating node shapes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33150/creating-node-shapes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However it is just oriented in one direction here. I'm sure one can improve it to make it easily rotatable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{arc style/.initial={}}
\pgfdeclareshape{half circle}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]

  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  % can add more anchors if necessary

  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]

  \beforebackgroundpath{
    % get and set options
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/arc style/.get=\tmp}
    \expandafter\tikzset\expandafter{\tmp}
    \tikz@options

    % get radius length and center coordinates
    \radius \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \centerpoint \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y

    % draw arc
    \advance\pgf@yb by \pgf@xa
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpatharc{90}{-90}{\pgf@xa}
    % change the last line to the following line if you want the half circle rotated in the other direction
    % \pgfpatharc{90}{270}{\pgf@xa}

    \pgfusepath{draw}
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[
    half circle,
    fill=red!10,  % can fill the circle if needed
    minimum width=2cm,
    arc style={red,thick}
    ] (c) {my half circle};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you have a bunch of `Missing character: There is no <char> in font nullfont!` errors.  The line `\radius \pgf@xa=\pgf@x` is the culprit, but I do not know how to correct it.

Comment: There was no issue/error in the past as far as I remember. Possibly due to a change in Tex version. Maybe see if the linked solution also gives the same errors.

Comment: Yes it gives the same error, so I posted the same comment there as well.